# Unable to install anything using apt

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gcc, dpkg

I was trying to install an earlier gcc and g++ (4.6.3) for compatibility reasons and now apt seems to be broken.  It appears that apt-get install behaves like this for everything, not just dpkg:

```
>> sudo apt-get install dpkg 
Reading package lists..
Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... 
Done 
dpkg is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to   
remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. After this
operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to
continue? [Y/n]
```

And choosing "Y" always results in this:

```
Setting up gcc (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I did run the configure script while trying to install gcc 4.6.3 and I might have given a bad value for the --target option.  I have tried various combinations of the following without success:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
apt-get remove/purge/autoremove gcc
```

Also, Synaptic claims there are no broken packages.

Advice is appreciated.

EDIT: In response to comments

```
>> sudo apt-get purge gcc
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gcc*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 42.0 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 278757 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gcc (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...

>> sudo dpkg -C
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 gcc                  GNU C compiler
```

Trying to remove any of these fails with complaints about dependencies:

```
>> sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep gcc
gcc                     install
gcc-4.6                     install
gcc-4.6-base:amd64              install
gcc-4.8                     install
gcc-4.8-base:amd64              install
gcc-4.9-base:amd64              install
libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64                install
libgcc1:amd64                   install

>> sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up gcc (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gcc

>> sudo dpkg -P gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8 1> command.out
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of gcc-4.9-base:amd64:
 libgcc1:amd64 depends on gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.1-0ubuntu1).

dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.9-base:amd64 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of gcc-4.8-base:amd64:
 libitm1:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libgomp1:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libstdc++6:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libgfortran3:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libasan0:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libtsan0:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libquadmath0:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 cpp-4.8 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).
 libatomic1:amd64 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1).

dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.8-base:amd64 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove gcc-4.8 which isn't installed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gcc-4.9-base:amd64
 gcc-4.8-base:amd64

>> sudo dpkg -P gcc-4.6 gcc-4.6-base
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of gcc-4.6:
 g++-4.6 depends on gcc-4.6 (= 4.6.4-6ubuntu2).

dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.6 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of gcc-4.6-base:amd64:
 gcc-4.6 depends on gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.4-6ubuntu2).
 libstdc++6-4.6-dev depends on gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.4-6ubuntu2).
 g++-4.6 depends on gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.4-6ubuntu2).
 cpp-4.6 depends on gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.4-6ubuntu2).

dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.6-base:amd64 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gcc-4.6
 gcc-4.6-base:amd64
```

Comment: Post the results of `apt-get purge gcc`, please. Also, `dpkg -C`.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg -P gcc-package-you-have-installed`? To identify the name of the package run `dpkg -L|grep gcc` and identify the one you want to remove.

Comment: first run `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc ` . Then after `sudo apt-get purge gcc` and `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @g_p: Thanks. But results in the same error message.

Comment: What is output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I have added the outputs as an edit to the op.

Comment: @YoMismo: I have added the outputs as an edit to the op.

Comment: @Pandya: I have added the outputs as an edit to the op.

Comment: try `dpkg -P gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8` and see if you still have problems, if you don't start from there, if you do remove 4.6 too and try again.

Comment: @YoMismo: I had problems with the first command but also the second. I posted the outputs as edits to the OP.

Comment: Then try `dpkg -P libgcc1` and see what packages if any depend on it, go removing depending packages until you can finally remove gcc-4.9-base, becarefull because dependencies may afect pacages that you don't want to remove, so check always before removing them.

Comment: The output of `sudo apt-get purge gcc` appears to succeed. Did you post the complete output? The last line is `Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1)`. using `dpkg -P` makes no sense in this context, since `dpkg -P` does not handle dependencies.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for taking some time to help. This was turning into a bottomless pit (I had already googled my brains out trying other solutions before posting here) so I opted to reinstall. My installation had other problems so I thought it might be a good time to start fresh.